# Show labels on x axis in vue-chartjs

Tags: charts, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I`m struggling with the esthetic aspect of my chart. Actually it lookes like this:
[image: My Chart]

Chart is showing data over time in 10mins intervals. With that number of labels it`s hard to see what column matches to time.
I would like to create ticks like on the image, so the chart would be way more readable. I looked into documentatnion and tried this but without effect:

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [
    {
      ticks: {
        drawTicks: true,
      },
    },
  ],
```

Comment: you could ticks.callback in order to show(or hide) the ticks in the format you want.

Comment: I am not sure if i getting it right but doing something like this:                            
  ```ticks: {
            drawTicks: true,
            callback: function (value: any, index: any, ticks: any) {
              return '$' + value;
            },
          },```

Comment: Yes and returning an empty string or undefined, the tick will not be shown.

Comment: That helps, a lot. I wonder whether can i as well modify the width of a cell inside the grid on the back?

Comment: you could ticks.stepSize. In version 3, there is also ticks.count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasting the answer from the comment section,
best way to work with ticks is by using callback function eg:

```
ticks: {
     callback: function (value: any, index: any, ticks: any) {               
              return 'What you want to return';             
      },           
}
```